# Select row and column in pyqt QTreeView

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a filter on qtreeview that recreates the rows and columns. Once the filter is removed of all text. ie filter = "". The qtreeview is recreated. I am looking to preselect a row when the qtreeview is recreated based on the selection when the user's filtered results.

I know that method I should be using is:
tree.setCurrentIndex(m)

I know that m should be:
m = QtCore.QModelIndex()

But, I can't seem to set the row and column in the QModelIndex that setCurrentIndex is happy with.

I know the selected item by text. Planning on getting the row index while the qtreeview is being recreated.

The qtreeview is setup like:

- a

  - 0
  - 1
- b

  - 2
  - 3
- c

  - 4
  - 5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Columns don't work how you would expect.

In your example, you do not have any columns, just rows.

To access item **a**, you should do the following:

```
>>> # setting up the model
>>> tree = QtGui.QTreeView()
>>> model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
>>> tree.setModel(model)

>>> # accessing data
>>> # To get item "a"
>>> a = tree.model().index(0, 0)
>>> a
<PySide.QtCore.QModelIndex(0,0,0x5805c40,QStandardItemModel(0x5805b30) )   at 0x7f9a81720148>
>>>
>> # to get item "a, 0"
>>> a0 = a.child(0, 0)
>>> a0
<PySide.QtCore.QModelIndex(0,0,0x7f9a88013d30,QStandardItemModel(0x5805b30) )   at 0x7f9a81720348>
```

Remember, that everything in Qt follows a parent/child relationship, including the QTreeView.
If this model seems fairly slow to you, you can look at providing methods to facilitate this for you (do not look at Qt for help, since QProxyModel has been **depricated** and should not be used.

In short, item **a** is a child of the model at (0, 0). Item **b** is at `(1, 0)`, and so forth. The children of item **a** can be referenced from **a**, using `a.child(row, column)`. Child **0** is at `(0, 0)` and child **1** is at `(1, 0)`.

Comment: tree has no attribute index. It did work with >>> a = model.index(0,0)

Comment: Sorry, typo in my code. It should be `tree.model().index`, not `tree.model.index`. Thank you for catching my error :D

`tree.model()` just returns a reference to `model`, which since you are working within the same scope is just the same thing here as `model.index`.